# How to compare value from three table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables which are shown below:

```
Employee
+---------------+-------------+--------+
| employee_name | street      | city   |
+---------------+-------------+--------+
| abhishek      | viman nagar | pune   |
| neha          | lohegaon    | pune   |
| prasahnt      | viman nagar | pune   |
| rahul         | viman nagar | pune   |
| rahul singh   | lohegaon    | mumbai |
+---------------+-------------+--------+

Works
+---------------+------------------+--------+
| employee_name | company_name     | salary |
+---------------+------------------+--------+
| prasahnt      | First Bank Corp  |  90000 |
| rahul         | First Bank Corp  |  85000 |
| abhishek      | First Bank Corp  |  95000 |
| rahul singh   | Second Bank Corp |  45000 |
| neha          | Second Bank Corp |  65000 |
+---------------+------------------+--------+

Company
+------------------+--------+
| company_name     | city   |
+------------------+--------+
| First Bank Corp  | pune   |
| Second Bank Corp | mumbai |
+------------------+--------+
```

I want to get all `employee_name` which have same city as of the company they are working in. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.employee_name
  FROM employee e,
       works w
       company c
 WHERE e.employee_name = w.employee_name
  AND w.company_name = c.company_name
  AND e.city = c.city;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying the same thing but was only using two and statements.

Comment: Can you upvote as well if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: You should use ANSI JOIN syntax. I'm upvoting the other answer because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do this with `JOIN` and a `WHERE`, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee e
JOIN Works w ON w.employee_name = e.employee_name
JOIN Company c ON c.company_name = w.company_name
WHERE c.city = e.city
```